# Set values of tibble cells to one if there are "enclosing" ones in columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

I'm working on a report that takes data from some files, makes a pivot table and calculates which `id` is "alive" at a certain period. However, I found an issue of missing data on some of the source files, and I need to fix it.

It's easier to explain this with an example:

The files are all imported into a single tibble that looks like this:

```
df.data %>% head()

### A tibble: 6 x 2
##  ID     REPORT_DATE
##  <chr>  <date>       
##1 9495   2019-08-14   
##2 1678   2019-08-14   
##3 0944   2019-08-14   
##4 6046   2019-08-14   
##5 7758   2019-08-14   
##6 2403   2019-08-14
```

After importing, I create a pivot table that looks like this:

```
df.pivot <- df.data %>% select(ID, REPORT_DATE) %>% 
  mutate(IN_REPORT=1) %>% arrange(ID, REPORT_DATE) %>% 
  spread(REPORT_DATE, IN_REPORT, fill=0) %>% head()

print(df.pivot %>% head)

### A tibble: 6 x 8
##  ID     `2019-08-14` `2019-08-21` `2019-08-28` `2019-09-04` `2019-09-11` `2019-09-18` `2019-09-25`
##  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
##1 8123            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
##2 0236            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
##3 0624            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
##4 1278            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
##5 2870            1            1            1            0            0            0            0
##6 5469            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
```

A value of `1` in a column implies that the ID is "alive", and a value of `0` implies that the ID is "not alive" (either because it hasn't "been born" or because it has "died")

This would work like a charm if each "alive" `ID` was present in each report. However, I've found that some IDs are missing, and they look like this:

```
print(df.pivot %>% 
  filter(ID %in% c('3989', '4188', '9941', '8996')))

### A tibble: 4 x 8
##  ID    `2019-08-14` `2019-08-21` `2019-08-28` `2019-09-04` `2019-09-11` `2019-09-18` `2019-09-25`
##  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
##1 4188             1            1            0            0            1            1            1
##2 9941             1            1            1            0            1            1            1
##3 3989             1            0            0            1            1            1            1
##4 8996             1            1            1            0            0            0            1
```

Let's take ID `3989` for example: It's present in the `2019-08-14` report, it's missing the following two reports, and then it reapears in the reports from `2019-09-04` onwards.

What I need, specifically, is, for each row:

1. Check if there are sequences of the type `1, 0, 1` (where there can be any number of zeros between ones.
2. Assign the value `1` to any intermediate zeros found

I've succesfully found the IDs with problems using this (maybe not an elegant solution, but I think it works):

```
df.ids_with_issues <- NULL

for(t in 2:(ncol(df.pivot)-1)) {
  df.temp <- df.pivot %>% 
    filter(
      .[t]==1, 
      .[t+1]==0,
      pmap_dbl(.[(t+1):ncol(df.pivot)], max)==1
    ) %>% select(ICCID)
  if(is.null(df.ids_with_issues)) {
    df.ids_with_issues <- df.temp
  } else {
    df.ids_with_issues <- df.ids_with_issues %>% union(df.temp)
  }
}

print(df.ids_with_issues)

### A tibble: 4 x 1
##  ICCID              
##  <chr>              
##1 3989
##2 4188
##3 9941
##4 8996
```

But I havent found how to deal with the second step of the solution.

Can you point me in the right way?

---

What I've thought might work:

- Add rows to the source tibble (`df.data`) to ensure that there are records corresponding to the IDs with issues.
  I would rather not do that, because it would force reprocessing the input, and although the data is small now, it's expected to grow soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simulated Data

```r
# the data frame
# A tibble: 7 x 8
     ID `2019-08-14` `2019-08-21` `2019-08-28` `2019-09-04` `2019-09-11` `2019-09-18` `2019-09-25`
  <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
1  4188            1            1            0            0            1            1            1
2  9941            1            1            1            0            1            1            1
3  3989            1            0            0            1            1            1            1
4  8996            1            1            1            0            0            0            1
5  1234            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
6  2345            1            1            1            1            1            0            0
7  2345            0            0            1            1            1            0            0
```

## Define the function

The tricky part to define a fcutnion which converts the pattern `1,...,1` (where `...` should be 0s of any length) to all 1s(`1,....,1`).

`rle` seems to come in handy in this case.

```r
replace_pattern_101 <- function(vec){
  stopifnot(length(setdiff(vec,c(0L,1L))) == 0L) # vec should only contain 0,1
  # with rle(Run Length Encoding)
  row_rle <- rle(vec)
  row_rle_val <- row_rle$values

  # patterns to find in `rle`, since the original vector has been already converted
  # in rle, so numbe of 0s or 1s doesn't matter now.
  pattern_101 <- c(1L,0L,1L)

  # structure the original vector to a vec which we can used to find the pattern
  # e.g c(1,0,1,0) to list(c(1,0,1),c(0,1,0))
  rolling <- map(
    seq(1:(length(row_rle_val) - length(pattern_101) + 1L)),
    ~ c(row_rle_val[.x:(.x+length(pattern_101)-1L)])
  )

  # find position that follows patter 1,0,1
  match_index <- which(map_lgl(rolling, ~ identical(pattern_101,.x)))

  if(length(match_index) > 0L) {
    row_rle_val[match_index + 1L] <- 1L
    row_rle$values <- row_rle_val
    # inverse rle
    inverse.rle(row_rle)
  } else {
    # otherwise return the original vector
    return(vec)
  }
}
```

```
> replace_pattern_101(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0))
> [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

## Use pmap to iterate by rows in data frame.

Once you have a function to do the pattern replacement, the remaining step is easy.

```r
library(tidyverse)
pmap_df(df,function(...){
  vals <- unlist(list(...))
  num_vals <- as.integer(vals[-1])
  num_vals
  # restructure to a data.frame
  as.list(c(
    vals[1],
    replace_pattern_101(num_vals) %>% setNames(names(vals)[-1])
  ))
})
```

## Results

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 8
     ID `2019-08-14` `2019-08-21` `2019-08-28` `2019-09-04` `2019-09-11` `2019-09-18` `2019-09-25`
  <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
1  4188            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
2  9941            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
3  3989            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
4  8996            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
5  1234            1            1            1            1            1            1            1
6  2345            1            1            1            1            1            0            0
7  2345            0            0            1            1            1            0            0
```

## Data

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(4188L, 9941L, 3989L, 8996L, 1234L, 2345L, 
2345L), `2019-08-14` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), `2019-08-21` = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), `2019-08-28` = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), `2019-09-04` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `2019-09-11` = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), `2019-09-18` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), `2019-09-25` = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. When I execute this step by step using your example, the `match_index` variable takes an `Empty`, and so, `length(match_index)` returns zero.

Comment: It is supposed to be 0 when no match is found. In this case, the original vector will be returned. Can you paste the line of data which this function doesn't work on?

Comment: I'll post the relevant snippets in my question... just give me a minute

Comment: I think I've found the issue, the pattern must be `c(1, 0, 1)`, not `c(1L, 0L, 1L)`. I'm testing it

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. I made some minor tweaks, but it works like a charm.

Comment: Can you coerce the numeric columns in your data frame to integer columns? Because, even though values look like 1,0, their type is actually double. And `1 == 1L` could be `FALSE` in some cases.